# Windows XP SP3 MySQL automatic backup error

Tags: java, mysql, windows-xp, backup

While trying to do automatic MYSQL backup using Java I keep getting the following error, and have been trying a work around all morning. The system is WindowsXP SP3, running Apache Tomcat 6, and Java 1.6.25

I keep getting this error:

```
ERROR com.busytech.barba.exception.BarbaException – java.io.IOException: Cannot run program “C:\Program”: CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
com.busytech.barba.exception.BarbaException: Cannot run program “C:\Program”: CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
at com.busytech.barba.persistence.BackUpAndRestoreDatabaseManager.getTableBackup(BackUpAndRestoreDatabaseManager.java:52)
at com.busytech.barba.servlet.checkcash.CashSummaryServlet.processRequest(CashSummaryServlet.java:95)
at com.busytech.barba.servlet.checkcash.CashSummaryServlet.doPost(CashSummaryServlet.java:495)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:298)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProcessor.process(Http11AprProcessor.java:864)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11AprProtocol.java:579)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$Worker.run(AprEndpoint.java:1665)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program “C:\Program”: CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Unknown Source)
at com.busytech.barba.persistence.BackUpAndRestoreDatabaseManager.getTableBackup(BackUpAndRestoreDatabaseManager.java:30)
at com.busytech.barba.servlet.checkcash.CashSummaryServlet.processRequest(CashSummaryServlet.java:95)
at com.busytech.barba.servlet.checkcash.CashSummaryServlet.doPost(CashSummaryServlet.java:495)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:298)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProcessor.process(Http11AprProcessor.java:864)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11AprProtocol.java:579)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$Worker.run(AprEndpoint.java:1665)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
at java.lang.ProcessImpl.create(Native Method)
at java.lang.ProcessImpl.(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(Unknown Source)
… 21 more
347156 [http-8080-4] ERROR com.busytech.barba.exception.BarbaException – java.io.IOException: Cannot run program “C:\Program”: CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
com.busytech.barba.exception.BarbaException: Cannot run program “C:\Program”: CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
at com.busytech.barba.persistence.BackUpAndRestoreDatabaseManager.getTableBackup(BackUpAndRestoreDatabaseManager.java:52)
at com.busytech.barba.servlet.checkcash.CashSummaryServlet.processRequest(CashSummaryServlet.java:95)
at com.busytech.barba.servlet.checkcash.CashSummaryServlet.doPost(CashSummaryServlet.java:495)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:298)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProcessor.process(Http11AprProcessor.java:864)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11AprProtocol.java:579)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$Worker.run(AprEndpoint.java:1665)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

This An Addition:
this is what i have done                                            try {

```
Process run = null;
        if (System.getProperty("os.name").toLowerCase().contains("window")) {
            run = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(SystemInformation.getWindowsMySQLDump() + " --host=" + host + " --port=" + port
                    + " --user=" + user + " --password=" + password
                    + " --compact --complete-insert --extended-insert "
                    + "--skip-comments --skip-triggers --skip-lock-tables --single-transaction " + database + " " + table);

        } else {
            run = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("mysqldump --host=" + host + " --port=" + port
                    + " --user=" + user + " --password=" + password
                    + " --compact --complete-insert --extended-insert "
                    + "--skip-comments --skip-triggers --skip-lock-tables --single-transaction " + database + " " + table);
        }
        InputStream in = run.getInputStream();
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
        int count;
        char[] cbuf = new char[BUFFER];

        while ((count = br.read(cbuf, 0, BUFFER)) != -1) {
            temp.append(cbuf, 0, count);
        }
        br.close();
        in.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure that this is a MySQL or Backup question, but from the error:

> Cannot run program “C:\Program”

It looks like you've forgotten to put quotes around a string somewhere.

If you try to run

```
c:\program files\myapp\something.exe
```

then it'll probably split at the first space, so you're trying to execute `c:\program` - which I doubt is an actual executable.
Try

```
"c:\program files\myapp\something.exe"
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the path your application (in your case probably MySQL) is installed.

C:\Program Files\MySQL\bin\mysql.exe

The white space in "Program Files" causes the problem and you do not put quotes on it.

"C:\Program Files\MySQL\bin\mysql.exe"

You could use [Apache Exec](http://commons.apache.org/exec/) to start processes from Java. This handles all the common stuff that can go wrong when it comes to start processes from a Java application

If you could provide further information how you try to start the process.

Here is what I recommend (an implementation using Apache Commons Exec).

```
CommandLine cmdLine = CommandLine.parse("C:\\Program Files\\MySQL\\bin\\mysqldump");
cmdLine.addArgument("--user=");
// add further args here
Executor executor = new DefaultExecutor();
OutputStream stdOut = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    PumpStreamHandler psh = new PumpStreamHandler(stdOut);
    executor.setStreamHandler(psh);

    try {
        int exitCode = executor.execute(cmdLine);
        String output = stdOut.toString();

        BufferedReader lineReader = new BufferedReader(new StringReader(output));

        String line;
        while ((line = lineReader.readLine()) != null) {
            log.debug("Reading line #{} - '{}'", lineCount, line);
        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        // handle the exception
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution I used, it works like on windows and linux the above suggestion to use apache commons exec:

```
        String cmdline = "mysqldump";
        DefaultExecuteResultHandler resultHandler = new DefaultExecuteResultHandler();
        CommandLine commandLine = CommandLine.parse(cmdline);
        commandLine.addArgument("--host=" + dbhost);
        commandLine.addArgument("--port=" + dbport);
        commandLine.addArgument("--user=" + dbuser);
        commandLine.addArgument("--password=" + dbpass);
        commandLine.addArgument(database);

        Set keys = table.keySet();
        for (Iterator i = keys.iterator(); i.hasNext();) {
            String key = (String) i.next();
            String value = (String) table.get(key);
            commandLine.addArgument(value);
        }
        commandLine.addArgument("-r");
        //outputFile might be a file on the server that can be downloaded
        //used apache file upload to download the files from the server
        commandLine.addArgument(outputFile);
        Executor executor = new DefaultExecutor();
        executor.execute(commandLine, resultHandler);
        resultHandler.waitFor();
```

And to restore the file to the server, Upload the file and here is the code to restore from a mysqldumpfile, this works if only mysql path has been set on the enviromental variables on windows but on linux it works as it is

```
        String cmdline = "mysql";
        DefaultExecuteResultHandler resultHandler = new DefaultExecuteResultHandler();
        CommandLine commandLine = CommandLine.parse(cmdline);
        commandLine.addArgument("--user=" + dbuser);
        commandLine.addArgument("--password=" + dbpass);
        commandLine.addArgument("--force");
        commandLine.addArgument("-v");
        commandLine.addArgument("-e");
        commandLine.addArgument("source");
        commandLine.addArgument(backUpFile);
        commandLine.addArgument(database);
        Executor executor = new DefaultExecutor();
        executor.execute(commandLine, resultHandler);
        resultHandler.waitFor();
```